# Выходят элементы за пределы родительского блока

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

не могу решить проблему, выходят элементы за пределы главного контейнера, такие как навигация и остальные блоки, как сделать так, чтобы навигация уменьшалась при сужении экрана, и блоки тоже. вот код:

```css
    .wrapper{
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 40px;

    }

    .menu{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
    }

    .menu__item{
     margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .menu__item .menu__link{
     display: block;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
     padding: 12px 25px;
     color: #EAD968;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     transition: all .3s;
    }
    
    .menu__item:first-child .menu__link{
     margin-left: 0;
     border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
    }
    
    .menu__item:last-child .menu__link{
     margin-left: 0;
     border-radius: 0 0 15px 0;
    }
    
    .menu__link:hover{
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }

    .offer-block{
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     max-width: 740px;
     margin: 40px auto;
     padding: 20px 30px;
     text-align: justify;
     border: 2px dashed #EAD968;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Home</a></li>
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">About</a></li>
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Blog</a></li>
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Services</a></li>
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>

    <div class="offer-block"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Выходят, потому что по-умолчанию у `.menu { display: flex; }` присутствуют еще и св-ва `flex-flow: row nowrap;` - горизонтально и без переноса на новую строку. + размер шрифта и отступы.

Предложу использовать медиазапросы:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper{
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 40px;

}

.menu{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu__item{
  width: 20%;
}

.menu__item+.menu__item{
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu__item .menu__link{
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  padding: 12px 5px;
  color: #EAD968;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: all .3s;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu__item:first-child .menu__link{
  margin-left: 0;
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.menu__item:last-child .menu__link{
  margin-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.menu__link:hover{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.offer-block{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  max-width: 740px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 2px dashed #EAD968;
}

@media (max-width:640px){
  .menu__item .menu__link{
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:640px){
  
  .menu {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
  
  .menu__item {
    width: 100%;    
  }
  
  .menu__item+.menu__item {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .menu__item .menu__link{
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Services</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="offer-block"></div>
</div>
```